# Termux: Evitar que el terminal elimine el banner al limpiar la consola

Tags: shell

**No quiero que cada vez que limpie mi terminal termux, se borre mi banner.**

```
echo '''
╭───────────────────────────────────╮
┊          ╔══╗───  ╔═╦═╗──────────         ┊
┊          ║══╣╔╦╗  ║║║║║╔═╗╔══╗╔═╗         ┊
┊          ╠══║║╔╝  ║║║║║║╬║║║║║║╬║         ┊
┊          ╚══╝╚╝─  ╚╩═╩╝╚═╝╚╩╩╝╚═╝         ┊
┊───────────────────────────────────┊
╰───────────────────────────────────╯
 ▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬
            [ versión : 1.3 ]
 ╚═════════════════════════════════════════╝''' | lolcat




PS1="\$ "
```

**Así se ve cada vez que abro una ventana nueva en mí terminal termux**. El problema es que cuando limpio la pantalla se borra mi banner, ¿habrá manera que no se borre?  **. Les agradecería de todo corazón que pudieran ayudar por favor :(**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Lo mas sencillo, y sin entrar en muchas complicaciones es crear un alias para el comando clear, en donde borre y lo vuelva a dibujar. Con eso lo "sobreescribis" pudiendo hacer la vuelta atras sin complicaciones. Tené en cuenta que los alias se establecen al abrir nuevamente la consola, o al volver a ejecutar el bashrc, por lo que si haces el cambio o ejecutas manualmente el bashrc, o reinicias la consola.

Para esto deberías abrir el archivo ".bashrc" que se suele encontrar en el home (~/.bashrc) y al final le agregás un alias tal que:

```
alias clear="/usr/bin/clear; echo..."
```

Deberías reemplazar el echo con el tuyo, logicamente.

Comment: Si, lo tenes que poner en un alias en el bashrc (O en el archivo que el terminal utiliza para inicializar el entorno)

Comment: No lo estás haciendo bien. El alias lo tenes que agregar dentro del .bashrc, te paso un ejemplo: alias l='ls -ltrh'

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurren dos formas. La primera es semejante a la sugerencia de Magus sólo que en lugar de sólo crear un `alias` con la instrucción, lo que propongo es primero crear el programa sencillo e instalarlo en una carpeta, luego el `alias` de `clear` tomara ese programa como sustituto.

Primero creamos el programa:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/clear

echo '''
╭───────────────────────────────────╮
┊          ╔══╗───  ╔═╦═╗──────────         ┊
┊          ║══╣╔╦╗  ║║║║║╔═╗╔══╗╔═╗         ┊
┊          ╠══║║╔╝  ║║║║║║╬║║║║║║╬║         ┊
┊          ╚══╝╚╝─  ╚╩═╩╝╚═╝╚╩╩╝╚═╝         ┊
┊───────────────────────────────────┊
╰───────────────────────────────────╯
 ▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬
            [ versión : 1.3 ]
 ╚═════════════════════════════════════════╝''' | lolcat
```

Como te puedes dar cuenta, utilicé la ruta completa de `clear` que es `/usr/bin/clear`.

Esto lo guardaré en un archivo llamado `custom_clear` dentro de la carpeta `/home/<mi usuario>/bin` que, si no existe, entonces la crearé con `mkdir /home/<mi usuario>/bin` que en la practica podrías hacerlo con un:

```
[[ -d ~${USER:-$USERNAME}/bin ]] || mkdir ~${USER:-$USERNAME}/bin
```

Luego le damos permisos de ejecución sólo para tu usuario. (Puedes darle los que quieras siempre y cuando tenga al menos permisos de ejecución para tu usuario).

```
chmod u=x,go= ~${USER:-$USERNAME}/bin/custom_clear
```

Luego podemos crear el alias con:

```
alias clear='/home/<tu usuario>/bin/custom_clear'
```

Y listo, puedes escribir `clear` que borrara todo menos ese molesto banner.

Sólo que para hacer persistente esto tendrías que poner en tu archivo `rc`. Como veo que tienes termux deberías ver qué shell estas corriendo, si `bash` o `zsh` o cualquier otra. Esto es por la localización del archivo `rc`. Digamos que estas corriendo `bash`, entonces tu archivo `$PREFIX/etc/bash.bashrc` tendría que tener ese `alias ...`.

Si estas corriendo `zsh` entonces debería ser tu archivo `$PREFIX/etc/zshrc`.

Lo puedes editar con `nano $PREFIX/etc/bash.bashrc` o con `vim $PREFIX/etc/bash.bashrc` y dentro tendría que tener

```
... etc etc
alias clear='/home/<tu usuario>/bin/custom_clear'
... etc etc
```

Y listo; cuando reinicies tu terminal te debería de correr *tipeando* `clear`.

Si quieres volver a la normalidad, ejecuta `unalias clear` y vuelve a editar tu archivo `rc` verificando que ya no se encuentre la declaración del alias.

Otra opción es jugando con la variable `PATH`.

Tu variable `PaTH` es un conjunto de datos que indican los directorios, separados por dos puntos, donde se deben de buscar los ejecutables.

Suponiendo que tienes localizado tu programa dentro de `/home/<tu usuario>/bin`, esa carpeta tiene que aparecer al inicio (o lo mas inmediato posible) de tu variable:

```
export PATH=/home/<tu usuario>/bin:$PATH
```

De esta manera cuando escribas `custom_clear` se ejecutara ese comando.

Con esto todavía puedes renombrar el nombre de ese archivo a `clear` (con `mv /home/<tu usuario>/bin/{custom_clear,clear}`) y sera el primer `clear` que busque, y no seguira hasta `/usr/bin/clear`. Entonces escribiendo simplemente `clear` se ejecutara ese pequeño programa.

Esto no es persistente debido a que la variable `PaTH` se reinicia cada que reinicias tu computadora o cada que abres una terminal nueva, por lo que tendrías que poner la instrucción:

```
export PATH=/home/<tu usuario>/bin:$PATH
```

dentro de tu archivo `rc`, es decir, editar con `vim $PREFIX/etc/bash.bashrc` o con `vim $PREFIX/etc/zshrc`, o usando `nano` en lugar de `vim`; como te acomodes.

Si quieres volver todo a la normalidad simplemente cambia el nombre de tu programa `clear` personalizado, o eliminalo, o regresa el valor del `PaTH` a su valor original que sería lo que hay a la derecha de `/home/<tu usuario>/bin:`, o simplemente edita de nuevo el archivo `rc` y reinicia la terminal.